# User based Collaborative filtering in R for recommendation of items

Tags: r, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am dealing with a user-item matrix  which has item data in it. The data is not numerical and not ordinal. Its purely categorical with no specific order. The items comprise of a vast list of > 8000 items.

Example,

```
UserID,Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4,Item5,Item6,Item7,Item8,Item9,Item10
10001, Apple,Bread,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
10002, Shoe,Pendrive,Wire,Pouch,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
10003, Apple, Mobile, Bottle,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
10001, Wire,Shoe,Pillow,Bottle,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
10004, Book, Sweater,Chair,Bag,Shoes,Mobile,Socks,Pillow,Pulses,Pouch
10005, Shoe, NA ,NA ,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA
10003, Socks,Ball, Mangoes, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA,NA
```

and so on..

I want to recommend next N items to a particular user through user based collaborative filtering.I would be glad if you could throw some light on the above methodology.

Comment: You're asking for help with what method to use. This is a machine-learning/statistical question. SO is for question about coding and programming. With editing your question _might_ be okay for another site. However, as written it is too broad for SO.